# Why is my NSArray intValue not working as expected?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray

In the following piece of code, loginString is 0 when an incorrect username password is entered and is 2061128143657912001 when a correct user name password is entered. However no matter what I do, I always get the pop up.

What am I missing?

```
//loginString is a 0 or a 2061128143657912001
if ([loginString intValue]>0) {

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:userName.text forKey:@"userNameKey"];
        [defaults setObject:password.text forKey:@"passwordKey"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }else {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Validation Error" message:@"Unable to validate Login/Password combination" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }
```

Comment: What is `loginString` and where is it declared and set?

Comment: NSMutableString *loginString;      declared in the same class in the header file. It is set in the XML parser functions. I have done an NSLog right above the code above and I get a 0 or 2061128143657912001

Comment: That’s not possible. An `int` is at most 2147483647.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try throwing in

```
NSLog(@"loginString  = %@",loginString);
NSLog(@"loginString  = %d",[loginString intValue]);
```

before the `if` statement to see if things are really what you think they are.

That done, see what happens if you reverse the `if` statement by

```
if ([loginString intValue] == 0) {
...
} else {
...
}
```

Or maybe even check `[loginString isEqualToString:@"0"]`.

Comment: very good observance I will try right now. Thanks for stating the obvious what I should have done :S

Comment: Yup sure enough I had released and nil'd loginString. Thanks for setting me on right track.

Comment: @jini: In light of Bavarious's observation, you may want to do your check with `![loginString isEqualToString:@"0"]` since it isn't clear what the `intValue` will be for a number larger than 2147483647.

Comment: `-[NSString intValue]` returns either `INT_MAX` or `INT_MIN` on overflow, and returns 0 if the string doesn’t begin with a valid number.

Comment: just a note --- even if you want to convert such a big number can not be handled using intValue -- you have to use longLongValue even if you have to convert.

Comment: still having some problems. please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367002/why-am-i-getting-strange-values-in-my-nsinteger-object. It is a different issue so had to open a new question since PengOne already answered my question for this round.